# I need to count instances of rows and delete duplicates based on multiple column values

Tags: excel, vba, csv

#### BASE TABLE

[image: Base Table]

#### FINISHED PRODUCT

[image: Finished Product]

So I'm working on sorting a CSV export into a format that will allow myself and the people in my department to quickly copy and paste information into a workbook that already exists. There are several formulas and codes that the existing workbook runs so I can't just create a new workbook using the formatting that the CSV export automatically does. Basically I need to take multiple rows of information that have multiple columns of identifiers and count/sum those rows and get rid of the duplicates but I need that row to have all of the corresponding information in the columns in it. I've tried the standard excel formulas and I can get sub totals or delete and sums, but it doesn't carry the rest of the information into it.

So final order of info to check if matched duplicates would be SKU, Floor Lvl, Detail, Room, Lable

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: This is what pivot tables do. No formulas required.

Comment: If you can show me how to get a pivot table to show me the information in the format of the Finished Product Link, then great that will work, but at this time the pivot table isn't doing what I need it to do. It is totaling all the items for the room or all the items at with that label. I need all the items for that room with that label and then I need it to total the next label for that room individually. exp: 1x8 for room 3932 = 6, 1x7 for room 3932 =3 not room 3932=9or 1x8 = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @teylyn suggests, Pivot Table is the way to go :

Select your data including headers

```
Insert > Pivot Table
```

In the "Row Labels" box, drop all your fields in order "Label" on top then "Style" then "SKU" ... except for "Count"

Drop the "Count" field in the "Values" box and set it to "Sum of Count"

```
PivotTable Tools > Design > Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form

PivotTable Tools > Design > Report Layout > Repeat All Item Labels

PivotTable Tools > Design > Grand Totals > Off for Rows and Columns

PivotTable Tools > Design > Subtotals > Do Not Show Subtotals
```

I get the same result as your "Finished Product".

Comment: AmBo, that worked! Thank you! I had tried using the pivot table before but I didn’t know how to get it to format. Now I can show my crew!

Answer (score 0):

As per existing comments/answers, PivotTable is probably the way to go. But maybe below is okay for you too (assuming it works). You'll need to assign PathToCSV.

```
Option explicit

Sub GroupCSVbyColumns()

Dim PathToCSV as string
PathToCSV = "C:\New Folder\ff.csv" 'Replace with actual path.'

If len(dir(PathToCSV)) >0 then

Dim ContentsOfCSV as string

Open PathToCSV for binary access read as #1
ContentsOfCSV = space$(lof(1))
Get #1,1, ContentsOfCSV ' Assumes file will fit in memory'
Close #1

Dim RowsInCSV() as string
RowsInCSV = split(ContentsOfCSV, vbNewline, -1, vbbinarycompare) ' Assumes rows are separated by new line character'

Const COMMA_DELIMITER as string = ","
Dim RowIndex as long

Dim OutputList() as string
Dim OutputCounts() as long

Redim OutputList(lbound(RowsInCSV) to ubound(RowsInCSV))

Redim OutputCounts(lbound(RowsInCSV) to ubound(RowsInCSV))

' "So final order of info to check if matched duplicates would be SKU, Floor Lvl, Detail, Room, Lable"
Not sure if it makes a difference in your case, but code below considers every column (apart from ' Count') when determining duplicates -- not just the ones you mentioned.'

Dim MatchResult as variant
Dim MatchesCount as long: MatchesCount = lbound(OutputList) 'this assignment ensures we leave the first element blank and reserved for header row, as we increment MatchCount first.
Dim CurrentRowText as string
Dim CurrentRowCount as long

For RowIndex = (lbound(RowsInCSV)+1) to ubound(RowsInCSV) ' Skip row of headers'

If len(RowsInCSV(RowIndex))>0 then

CurrentRowText = left$(RowsInCSV(RowIndex),instrrev(RowsInCSV(RowIndex),comma_delimiter,-1, vbbinarycompare)-1)

CurrentRowCount = clng(mid$(RowsInCSV(RowIndex),1+instrrev(RowsInCSV(RowIndex),comma_delimiter,-1, vbbinarycompare)))

' Filter function might perform better than Match below. '
MatchResult = application.match(CurrentRowText, OutputList,0)

If isnumeric(MatchResult) then
OutputCounts(clng(MatchResult)) = OutputCounts(clng(MatchResult)) + CurrentRowCount

Else
MatchesCount = MatchesCount + 1
OutputList(MatchesCount) = CurrentRowText
OutputCounts(MatchesCount) = OutputCounts(MatchesCount) + CurrentRowCount

End if

End if

Next RowIndex

Dim TemporaryArray() as string
Dim ColumnIndex as long

TemporaryArray = split(RowsInCSV(lbound(RowsInCSV)),comma_delimiter,-1, vbbinarycompare)

Dim OutputTable(1 to (MatchesCount+1), 1 to (ubound(TemporaryArray)+1))

' Assign all headers from header row; done outside of loop below as all columns are looped through.'
For ColumnIndex = lbound(OutputTable,2) to (ubound(OutputTable,2))
OutputTable(1,ColumnIndex) = TemporaryArray(ColumnIndex-1)
Next ColumnIndex

For RowIndex = (lbound(OutputTable,1)+1) to ubound(OutputTable,1)

TemporaryArray = split(OutputList(rowindex-1),comma_delimiter,-1, vbbinarycompare)

For ColumnIndex = lbound(OutputTable,2) to (ubound(OutputTable,2)-1)

OutputTable(RowIndex,ColumnIndex) = TemporaryArray(ColumnIndex-1)

Next ColumnIndex

OutputTable(RowIndex,ColumnIndex) = OutputCounts(RowIndex-1)

Next RowIndex

Dim OutputSheet as worksheet
Set OutputSheet = Thisworkbook.worksheets.add
 OutputSheet.range("A1").resize(ubound(OutputTable,1),ubound(OutputTable,2)).value2 = OutputTable

Else
Msgbox("No file found at " & PathToCSV)
End if

End sub
```

Untested, written on mobile.

Comment: Chillin, thank you for your time, AmBo got me squared away!